# AJAX login for Spring security backend with AngularJs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, spring, spring-security

I have the following stack of the frameworks - Spring 4.x that provides the REST services and AngularJs 1.4.7 that is used for front end. I would like to implement the registration page on my web-project.

I have the following configuration for the Spring security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityApplicationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImplementation userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    // declare all public resources and URIs
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/pages/index.html", "/pages/public/**", "/resources/css/**", "/resources/img/**", "/resources/js/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "logout").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register").permitAll();

    // any other resources and URIs must pass authentication procedure.
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .successHandler(new AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()))
            .loginPage("/pages/public/security/login.html")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/resources/public/login.html")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

And Ajax authentication handler implementation

```
public class AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler defaultHandler;

    public AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler(AuthenticationSuccessHandler defaultHandler) {
        this.defaultHandler = defaultHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(request.getHeader("-----------------------------------------------------X-Login-Ajax-call"));

        if ("true".equals(request.getHeader("X-Ajax-call"))) {
            response.getWriter().print("ok");
            response.getWriter().flush();
        }
        else {
            defaultHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my front end registration controller:

function ($scope, $log, $http, $window, customerInformation) {

```
$scope.ProcessRegistration = function () {
    var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + '/pages/index.html#';

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/register',
        data: newCustomerInformation,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log(data + ' success');
            customerInformation.setCustomerType(newCustomerInformation.customerType);
            Login(newCustomerInformation.login, newCustomerInformation.password);

        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log(data + ' error');
            url += '/register';
            $window.location.href = url;
            displayErrorMessages(data);
        });
};

var Login = function (login, password) {
    console.log("performing login for the user with credentials: login " + login + " password: " + password);
    var postData = 'username=' + password + '&password=' + password;

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/login',
        data: postData,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "X-Ajax-call": 'true'
        }
    })
        .success(function(response) {
            if (response.data == 'ok') {
                //redirect if success
                console.log("Successfully authenticated from the function 'Login'");
            }
            else {
                console.log("BS !!");
            }
        });
};
}]);
```

Basically, the front end does 2 things:

1. it sends customer information to the server, if everything is fine then
2. it tries to authenticate with the newly provided user login and password.

However, the problem is in the response from the server i.e. at the front-end `Login.success(function(response))` I see that the server sends me the login html page.

The questions are the following: how can I 'submit' this form in AngularJs with the customer credentials (login and password)? Is this given fact that the server sends me the html login form, kinda, normal?

Comment: Yes, it's normal... Seeing you're essentially using core [jHipster](http://jhipster.github.io/) code... you should [read the docs on authentication](http://jhipster.github.io/security.html)

Comment: Yep, you are right. I am using his code. I will add a link to his repository. However, I don't fully understand how can I submit the form ...

Comment: :) jHipster is a `project` not a person :) But that's not germane to the issue... [the docs](http://jhipster.github.io/security.html) describe authentication in detail :)

Comment: Well, I have used the following project https://github.com/jhades/spring-mvc-angularjs-sample-app to get an inspiration ))

Comment: I might suggest starting fresh with a greenfield jHipster project and it should work out of the box. :) ... Here's [A Working Sample App](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app)

Comment: I don't want to stick to the any projects/frameworks except the angularjs and spring. Could you recommend any post where I could see the proper rest-login implementation?

Comment: jHipster IS spring/angularjs. My last comment links to a working sample

Comment: How can I prevent the server without sending me a login form?